# Estructura de pagina - Layout de multiples div

Tags: html, css, layout

Necesito construir esta estructura en HTML y CSS: [image: Imagen]

No tengo conocimiento de Grid y Flexbox, que a mi entender son las unicas soluciones posibles.

Comment: ¿con bordes negros y espacio entre ellos? o simplemente ¿rectángulo grande y dos pequeños sin espacio ni borde?

Comment: Sinplemente un rectangulo grande y los dos al lado, el espacio en medio creo que podria ajustarlo con margin o algo especifico de grid/flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styles.css

```
*{ /*para todos los elementos (*), quitamos margin y padding por defecto, necesario para eliminar algunos márgenes de según que navegadores*/
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#divContenedor { /*contiene dos divs, el cuadro grande y el que contiene a los dos chicos*/  
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
width:100vw; /*100vw=100% del ancho del view*/
height:100vh; /*100vh=100% del alto del view*/
}

#divGrande {
 width:67%; /*se reparte el ancho con el divContenedorChicos, que será del 33%*/
background:pink;
}

#divContenedorChicos { /*div que contiene a los dos pequeños en vertical (column)*/
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
width:33%;
height:100%;
justify-content:flex-start;
}

#divChico1 {
width:100%; /*todo el ancho del padre (divContenedorChicos) */
height:50%; /*la mitad de altura del padre*/
background:blue;
}

#divChico2{
width:100%;
height:50%;
background:green;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divContenedor">
     <div id="divGrande"></div>
     <div id="divContenedorChicos">
             <div id="divChico1"></div>
             <div id="divChico2"></div>
     </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Luego ya, si quieres bordes o márgenes, mete `<div>` dentro de `#divGrande`, `#divChico1` y `#divChico2` con lo que quieras y mantendrás la estructura.

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, saludos